# jQuery Coding Standards & Best Practices (Separating Events and Functions)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been reading [this article](http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/jquery-standards/#Events), which suggests separating events from functions. But how do I `e.preventDefault()` like this?

```
$("#myLink").on("click", function(){...}); // BAD


// GOOD
function myLinkClickHandler(){...}
$("#myLink").on("click", myLinkClickHandler);
```

Comment: your function myLinkClickHandler will receive as parameter the event. you can then prevent default in your myLinkClickHandler method!

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the supposed "bad" method. The article you link to is only one person's opinion.

Comment: and as another person's opinion, that separation is only beneficial (and therefore advised) when you are reusing that function. otherwise you are creating excess code, and therefore slowing down the rendering of your page, for no reason other than someone's generic "standard".

Comment: and btw, i read through that page ... there are a number of bad practices he lists as "best". qualifying your selectors with tag names (slows it down for no reason), the use of context (delegation is much better, context is super old school), specify *dataType* on AJAX calls (when it is internal, you should set the headers of the page called explicitly from that page), chaining of `.on()` events (you should use the object-based `.on({method1:function(){},method2:function(){}})` syntax), the list goes on.

Comment: I see this is closed due to "primarily" being opinion based.I asked a very specific question, I wasn't asking people for their opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, defining a function first and then assign it as an event listener is recommended if:

1. The same function can be used as an event handler for another event. In this case, defining the handler inline would mean duplicating code.
2. You want to be able to remove that specific event handler easily. In this case, defining the event handler inline implies that, to remove it, you may have to use the `.off` method with event namespaces to avoid the risk of removing other event handlers that may be attached to the same object and event.

But if you're only setting an event handler that won't be reused, I'd define it inline, because, at least for me, it makes it easier to trace which code is executed as a response to an event.

Anyway, if you want access to the `Event` object that jQuery passes to the event handlers, you can do easily no matter what approach you're using:

```
//inline
$('#myLink').on('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });

//previous function:
function linkClickHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

$('#myLink').on('click', linkClickHandler);
```

jQuery always passes an `Event` object to the handler, it does not matter where the function was defined. In fact, jQuery won't know which approach you've used.

Comment: I thought this as well, but the page refreshes even with your example copy and pasted.

Comment: Have you checked for any errors that in the console. Maybe there's some typo.

Comment: First thing I check - it simply refreshes -

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint inside the handler, to check whether it is being called at all? Maybe there's an error in the jQuery selector and you are attaching the handler to and empty object.